# how can I change width of a checkbox Without transform Scale

Tags: html, css, styles, width

I seem to strugle finding a way to change **only** the ***width*** of a checkbox.
I know you can increase the scale with e.g. `transform: scale(2);` but I only want to increase the width let's say

```
#myCheckBox {
 width: 50px
}
```

Why doesn't this work?

Comment: Maybe related : [How to set checkbox size in HTML/CSS?](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-set-checkbox-size-in-html-css/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume your `HTML CODE` is:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="checkBox1" checked id="myCheckBox">
```

So you can style your **check box** by this `CSS CODE`:

```
#myCheckBox {
  transform : scale(3,1); /*3 for width,1 for height*/
}
```

**NOTE** : 1 value is the default value of scale

Comment: thanks a lot i didnt know about the comma and XY within the scale :D

Comment: It seems you get the idea well, you're welcome. @Zyfella